# CASE WHEN on SPLIT - Bigqery

Tags: google-bigquery

spend_data AS (
SELECT day as date, LOWER(campaign) campaign,
(SPLIT(client_name,"-")[SAFE_OFFSET(3)]) as Country,
sum(costs) as spend,

The above simply breaks out country from the string provided, as country. I then want to go further and classify the regions in accordance to our own convention.

I get the error that 'country isn't defined' when I on later line add in the case when statements.

What is the best approach here?

Comment: You can't reference an alias you defined in the same level of your query. Maybe you could use a WITH statement to create a temporary table with such splits and then select from the temporary table

Comment: Do you have an example of how you might do this?